# Pandas '_stringify_path' is not defined after installing holoviews package

Tags: python, pandas, pip, package, holoviews

**Background:**
What started as an attempt to get `holoviews` package installed turned into a monster. I have zero computer science education, so I'm sorry for my ignorance here. Anyway, I don't even care about holoviews anymore, I just want to go back to simpler times when I could `import pandas as pd` and `pd.read_csv()` without issues.

I installed holoviews using pip3. But I still kept getting a 'no module found error' when trying to `import holoviews as hv`. So then I installed with pip3, same issue. Then I tried conda. Now I have dug myself into a hole. Here are all my installs that created this mess:
(desperation)

```
pip3 install holoviews
pip install holoviews
pip3 install bokeh
pip3 install bokeh==0.12.15
pip3 install holoviews==1.10.4
pip3 install --upgrade bokeh
pip3 install --upgrade holoviews
pip3 install holoviews[all]
pip3 install git+https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews.git
```

Alas `conda install holoviews` got rid of my "no module found" error. But now I can't import data, so I'm screwed.

**Goal:**
I am trying to import a csv for a project I've been working on for a while. So, it worked before my attempt at incorporating holoviews. I also tried the following code without importing holoviews.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import seaborn as sns
from itertools import cycle, islice
import holoviews as hv

page_traffic = pd.read_csv("traffic_by_page.csv")
```

**Traceback and Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-0e223cd558a7>", line 1, in <module>
    page_traffic = pd.read_csv("traffic_by_page.csv")

  File "/Users/margaretsant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    _doc_read_csv_and_table.format(

  File "/Users/margaretsant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 433, in _read
    kwds["compression"] = compression

  File "/Users/margaretsant/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 280, in _infer_compression

NameError: name '_stringify_path' is not defined
```

**What I've tried:**

```
conda remove holoviews
```

This gets stuck for hours at the `Solving Environment` part so I terminated it

```
conda remove pandas
```

Same story

```
 pip3 --update pandas
```

I'm going for hail marys at this point. I guess pip3 updated pandas, but im still getting the same traceback

**Information I Googled and don't understand**

```
pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : None
python           : 3.7.1.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Darwin
OS-release       : 18.7.0
machine          : x86_64
processor        : i386
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : en_US.UTF-8
LANG             : en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 0.25.3
numpy            : 1.18.4
pytz             : 2020.1
dateutil         : 2.8.1
pip              : 20.1
setuptools       : 46.2.0.post20200511
Cython           : None
pytest           : None
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : 3.0.3
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.8
lxml.etree       : None
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 2.11.2
IPython          : 7.14.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.9.0
bottleneck       : 1.3.2
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
lxml.etree       : None
matplotlib       : 3.2.1
numexpr          : None
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : None
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : None
pytables         : None
pytest           : None
pyxlsb           : None
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.4.1
sqlalchemy       : None
tables           : None
tabulate         : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : None
xlsxwriter       : 1.2.8
numba            : None
```

I have the default Mac python installed `Python 2.7.9` and Python 3 `Python 3.7.1`.

Comment: I'm not following how this is related to HoloViews. You are pinning a very old version of HoloViews and an even older version of Bokeh. I'd recommend just going with the latest versions. Also you seem also to have a very old version of pandas. Just go with recent versions of all the libraries and there should be no issue.

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think holoviews is the problem. A possible way of solving this: you can try to read up (and google) on creating a separate environment in which you install only the packages needed: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html  Or just use anaconda where everything comes already pre-installed: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Comment: @philippjfr I think when i installed holoviews it installed another version of pandas that was interfering with the current version. I also think this happened with conda install. I ended up just removing anaconda all together and reinstalling it, and it fixed the problem i was having with importing csvs with pandas.

Comment: @ Sander van den Oord  I think setting up a separate environment would have been the best idea. I usually dont do this because I'm lazy / not-so-great a programmer, but I'm gonna try adopting this in the future